# WordPress deployment creation failed Google Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I tried several times to deploy wordpress with click to deploy on Google Compute Engine and not works this is the error:

> > Creando la implementación 10 de mar. de 2015 0:20:38
> >     deploymentCoordinator: PENDING wordpress: PENDING 10 de mar. de 2015
> >     0:20:50 ... 10 de mar. de 2015 0:22:16 deploymentCoordinator:
> >     DEPLOYING wordpress: DEPLOYING 10 de mar. de 2015 0:22:29 ... 10 de
> >     mar. de 2015 0:23:17 deploymentCoordinator: DEPLOYED wordpress:
> >     DEPLOYING 10 de mar. de 2015 0:23:29 deploymentCoordinator: DEPLOYED
> >     wordpress: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
>
> Replica acstore-q3vd failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica
>   State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2
>   consecutive times.

Comment: Are you using a Free Trial account ? Please check that you are not hitting any free quota limit. In this case as a workaround you can create a new project with billing enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you ssh into the instances and run the following command, it often explains the source of the problem:

```
tail -f /gagent/metaOutput/*
```